# How to find the size of an array as an int

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, integer

I apologize if the answer is extremely obvious.
I wrote this small snippet of code that initializes a vector from an array

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  vector<int> vec = {begin(arr), end(arr)};
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        cout << vec[i];
```

The code works fine, the only thing that bugs me is having to know the array size. The second parameter of the for,

```
i < 5;
```

just seem a bit too easy and not as accurate in a bigger piece of code. is there any way that I can have the code deduce the number of elements in the array as an integer and use that rather than stating the actual number of elements myself? I tend to find this annoying when using most arrays or vectors. I'm sure it would be a better habit to write something that would deduce the answer for me because I'm sure it could lead to miscalculations where user input is required and there is no limit to the amount of elements they input.

Comment: `vector` has a function for that. So does `std::array`, which you should be using instead of built-in arrays. `vector` also lets you use an initializer list, so the array is pointless anyway. And you'd normally use a ranged-for loop or an algorithm, so knowing the size is also pointless for that.

Comment: @chris: `std::array` requires that you specify the size (or you should implement a `make_array`).

Comment: @Jarod42, So do built-in arrays.

Comment: @chris: No, as in OP's example `int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, you don't (explicitly) specify that the size is `5`.

Comment: @Jarod42, You never said explicitly. You're still providing the size via an initializer list, much like you would with `make_array`.

Answer (score 3):

To get the size of `int arr[]`, you can use `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)`.

To initialize the `vector<int>` with the values from the array, you can use:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
vector<int> vec (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr) );
```

To iterate all its values of the vector, you can use (`size()` will give you the size of the vector):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    cout << vec[i];
```

**p.s.** In C++11, you can even use [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for (auto elem : vec)
    std::cout << elem;
```

Answer (score 2):

- To get the size of the array:

  ```
  template <typename T, std::size_t N>
  constexpr std::size_t array_size(const T(&)[N]) { return N; }
  ```
- `std::vector` already has a member method `size()`.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the vector without hard coding its size:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
   cout << vec[i];

for ( vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it )
   cout << *it;
```

If you are using C++11,

```
for ( auto item : vec )
   cout < item;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your code,

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
vector<int> vec = {begin(arr), end(arr)};
```

is OK, assuming that `begin` and `end` are `std::begin` and `std::end`.

---

The following loop,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    cout << vec[i];
```

is ungood in three ways:

- wrong loop, should use a range-based `for`.
- hardcoded size, should use `vec.size()` or equivalent.
- not using braces for the loop body easily leads to maintenance problems.

Corrected as an ordinary C++03 `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)vec.size(); ++i)
{
    cout << vec[i];
}
```

The cast is there to suppress a warning about signed/unsigned mismatch, which otherwise is likely to be produced.

In passing, note that for type `int` there is no problem with maintenance possibly changing the meaning of this cast, or the meaning being different than intended.

Still, it might yield a false positive in a clever automated search for C-style casts. Personally I avoid it by using a function `count_of`. So if I for some reason had chosen the C++03 `for` loop I would have written something like

```
for( int i = 0; i < count_of( vec ); ++i )
{
    cout << vec[i];
}
```

But instead you can simply use the C++11 range-based `for`, like this:

```
for( auto const value : vec )
{
    cout << value;
}
```

---

Where you do need the signed integer size of a container, which might be a raw array, consider leveraging `std::begin` and `std::end`:

```
#include <stddef.h>  // ptrdiff_t
#Include <iterator>  // std::begin, std::end

using Size = ptrdiff_t;

template< class Container >
auto count_of( Container& c )
    -> Size
{ return std::end( c ) - std::begin( c ); }
```

I'm not sure if it's worthwhile to specialize for raw array, but if you need `constexpr` then you need to do that, e.g.

```
template< class Item, Size n >
auto constexpr count_of( Item (&a)[n] )
    -> Size
{ return n; }
```

Disclaimer: none of the code touched by compiler.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness: This problem was what [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) was created for. (C++11)

```
// This is statically allocated, unlike vector 
// which uses dynamic allocated memory.
std::array<int, 5> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 

// Different iterations methods:
for ( auto & elem : arr ) {
    cout << elem << endl;
}

for ( int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
}

for ( auto it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); ++it) {
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```